# Why does my 2-d array display the correct value at an index when I am putting the values in, but not what I try to access them later? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a program that reads in a linux shadow file, delimits each line into an ID, a salt, and a hash for the encrypted password. I created a 2-d char array for each of these values, and am filling it up with the values as I go through each line. As I enter these values into the array, I print it out just to show that it is entering the correct value like this:

`printf(id: %s, salt: %s", ids[num_accounts], salts[num_accounts]);`

The results of this are as follows:

```
id: root, salt: NrF46O1p
id: seed, salt: wDRrWCQz
id: user1, salt: LGOwUL7Q
id: user2, salt: CL5Fr2bN
id: user3, salt: Un/lqxkl
id: user4, salt: Lx2zrG31
id: user5, salt: 6R1eYOtL
```

This is done as each value is entered. After all the values are entered and the program has exited the while loop, there is another for-loop to print out all the values (for debugging purposes)

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_accounts; i++){
     printf("salt %d: %s\n", i, salts[i]);
```

The results of this are as follows:

```
salt 0:
salt 1:
salt 2: 6R1eYOtL
salt 3: 6R1eYOtL
salt 4: 6R1eYOtL
salt 5: 6R1eYOtL
salt 6: 6R1eYOtL
salt 7: (null)
```

Here is my code for allocating the 2-d arrays and filling it up:

```
char **ids;
char **hashes;
char **salts;

hashes = malloc((num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));
salts = malloc((num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));
ids = malloc((num_accounts + 1) * sizeof(char*));

for(int i = 0; i < num_accounts; i++){
     hashes[i] = malloc(88);
     salts[i] = malloc(8);
     ids[i] = malloc(15);
}

shadow = fopen("shadow", "r");
num_accounts = 0;
while(fgets(shdw_line, SHDW_LINE_LEN, shadow)!=NULL){
     char *token = strtok(shdw_line, ":");
     char *shdw_hash = strtok(NULL, ":");
     if(strcmp(shdw_hash, "*")!=0 && strcmp(shdw_hash, "!")!=0){
        ids[num_accounts] = token;
        token = strtok(shdw_hash, "$");
        token = strtok(NULL, "$");
        salts[num_accounts] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "$");
        hashes[num_accounts] = token;
        printf("%d: id: %s, salt: %s\n", num_accounts, ids[num_accounts], salts[num_accounts]);
        num_accounts++;
     }
}
```

I am wondering why the array gets overwritten with the last value that gets entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

salts[i] = malloc(8);

change to

salts[i] = malloc(9);//1 more for flag end of string its basic background 
knowledge

---

salts[num_accounts] = token;//will give you source string's pointer so you will get all same

change to

strcpy(salts[num_accounts],token);

Comment: Thank you. It seems so obvious when looking at it with the correct implementation next to it.